# Mongodb $addtoSet is not working in node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In this problem, mongo `$addToSet` could not add a `Store` in my `stores` (where I commented out worked) but it can give me a duplicate ID. What is my mistake here? How can I solve it? Thanks.

```
stores: {
      count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
      store: [`enter code here`
        {
          ref: 'Store',
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
        }
      ]
    },)
try {
  console.log(req.body);
  const updateStore = await Store.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true
  });
  const {users} = req.body;
  console.log(users);
   users.map(async (el)=>{
     console.log(el);
     const user = await User.findById(el);
     return await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: el },
      {
        // stores: {
        //   count: user.stores.count + 1,
        //   // store: [ ...user.stores.store, req.params.id]
        // },
        // stores: {
        //    store: [ ...user.stores.store, req.params.id]
        // },
         $addToSet:{'stores.$.store' : req.params.id}
      },
      { new: true}
    );
  })

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    updateStore
  });
 }catch(err) {
   console.log(err);
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
User.update(
      { _id: el },
         $push: {
    'stores.store':req.params.id
} ,
      },
     
    );
  })
```

to avoid duplicate entries in the array use `$addToSet`

```
User.update(
      { _id: el },
         $addToSet: {
    'stores.store':req.params.id
} ,
      },
     
    );
  })
```

In case you have array of objects use the following

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 5,
  "data.quizzes.wk": {
    $ne: 5
  }
},
{
  $push: {
    "data.quizzes": {
      wk: 5,
      score: 55555
    }
  }
})
```

Try this example [Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CH0sqwQ9H0R) ---  for array of strings

Try this example [Mongoplayground1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jk1ib8NoehH) ---- for array of objects

Comment: set also not work in this can you give a me a simple code example which similar case like me

Comment: I also want to track record of previous values

Comment: I have modified and updated the answer . check it out

Comment: Here it can be duplicate value, How could i handle it?? Using upsert??

Comment: I have modified and updated the answer . check it out